# Create overlay on video in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I am trying to use a video as a background in a div and I can't manage to display the div's content video overlay..

Here is my HTML:

Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.

```
    <div class="container text-center">
        <h1>Personal Portfolio</h1>
        <p>Graphic design, Web developement & Social Media</p>
        <img class="image-responsive" src="https://s32.postimg.org/qrpva9fed/profile.jpg" style="border-radius:50%; width:15%">
    </div><!-- End container -->
</div><!-- End jumbotron-->
```

And here is my CSS:

```
    .jumbotron{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container .text-center{
  z-index: 1000 !important;
}
#video-background {
  position: absolute; 
  background: #222;
    width:100%;
    background-size: cover;
    transition: 1s opacity;
    opacity: 0.7;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

I have tryed using z-index with no luck, here's a link to codepen:

https://codepen.io/Alique/pen/JKRxZd

Many thanks before hand.

Comment: Where are you putting your video exactly ? i can't find any video in your `codepen`

Comment: would you look at it again? it is inside the .jumbotron div

Comment: ok, check the answer i changed your code. its all working know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing that was making the issue is that you have to use `pseudo elements` for `overlaying` not opacity, and also use the second `section` with `position:absolute` and the first `section` with `position:relative`, so that the second `section` comes at the top of the first `section` then the `z-index` will work as you want.

**HTML**

Wrapped your `video` in a div

```
<div class="video-background">
<video autoplay="" loop="" class="fillWidth fadeIn animated" poster="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/coverr/poster/Traffic-blurred2.jpg" id="video-background">
<source src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/coverr/mp4/Traffic-blurred2.mp4" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
```

**CSS**

```
.jumbotron{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding:0px !important;
 }
.container .text-center{
  z-index: 1000 !important;
}
.video-background:before{
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 position: absolute;
 content: "";
 background-color: #000;
 opacity: 0.39;
 z-index: 6;
}
.video-background {
  position: relative; 
 background: #222;
width:100%;
z-index:5;
  }
#video-background{
 background-size: cover;
transition: 1s opacity;
}

.cover-text{
position:absolute;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
z-index:9999;
top:5em;
}

.cover-text h1, .cover-text p{
color:#fff !important;
 }
```